# Data upgrade script for base enum from AX 4.0 to AX 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Kindly assist me with some ideas in writing the Upgrade script for upgrading the base enum in AX from AX 4.0 to AX 2009.

Also i would like to know the sequence of upgrading and the reasons behind. Like is it first we need to upgrade Enum? then Edt's etc etc.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please describe what you want to upgrade. Did you change the enum values?

Comment: Good practice is to always change enums to a higher number lets say from an enum range of 1-30 create one of value 100, etc...you won't run into those kind of problems...

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, please accept the answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe your enum upgrade problem. List your enum values and describe why your enum field need an upgrade.

Comment: Hi Jan, I just want to know the sequence to upgrade i.e. what has to be upgraded first enum or edt or tables etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Look for what others have done: see  class ReleaseUpdateDB39_Basic method migrateIntercompanyCommerceGateway2AIF.

Do not delete enum values, rather rename and prefix with "DEL_", then change the ConfigurationKey to "SysDeletedObjects40". This allow you to reference the old obsolete values in the upgrade script.

See also [Frameworks Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa659223.aspx) and [How to Write Data Upgrade Scripts](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22129).